# Common Lisp & CFFI: modifying a global variable

Tags: common-lisp, cffi

my goal is to modify a C global variable.

Assuming I have the following  C header file:

```
/* test.h */
int global_variable;
```

and the C source file:

```
/* test.c */
#include "stdio.h"
#include "test.h"

extern int global_variable;
void test(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "Global variable: %d\n", global_variable);
}
```

The global_variable correctly appears inside the shared library generated by

```
gcc -c -fPIC test.c
gcc -shared -o libtest.so test.o
```

My lisp interface looks like this:

```
(ql:quickload :cffi)

(cffi:define-foreign-library libtest
    (:unix (:default "./libtest"))
  (t (:default "./libtest")))

(cffi:use-foreign-library libtest)

(cffi:defcvar ("global_variable" *global-variable*) :int)

(cffi:defcfun "test" :void )
```

I can call test with no error, but I cannot modify the global_variable with

```
(setf *global-variable* 42)
```

I get a warning undefined variable, and then defines (I assume) a new variable.

So the question is how to modify the global_variable in common lisp (sbcl)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I could write a C function, e.g. void set_g(int g) {global_variable = g;}, setting the global_variable, and then write an interface in common lisp for set_g. But I assume there must be another way.

Comment: It seems to work for me after I added the missing `fclose(fp);` to the C function.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't know if I should ask a new question, or ask it here. Assuming that I have a global variable that is a structure: 
struct block {
    float x;
    int a, b, c;
};
It is defined in lisp as:
(cffi:defcstruct block
  (x :float)
  (a :int)
  (b :int)
  (c :int))
After that how do I proceed to modify it?

Answer (score 0):

For your struct, something like this should work:

```
(cffi:with-foreign-object (ptr 'block)
        ;; setf the slots
        (setf (cffi:foreign-slot-value ptr 'block 'a) 12) ...etc.
```